# Para que serve o Array.GetLength?

Tags: c#, array

Para saber o tamanho de um vetor, eu posso usar apenas o `nomedovetor.Length`, certo?

Eu vi um exemplo numa estrutura `for`, onde usava-se `GetLength(0)` ou  `GetLength(1)` para capturar as dimensões de um *array* de linhas e colunas.

Poderiam me explicar esse *0* e *1* entre parêntesis? Eu não o entendi muito bem.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 7):

> Para saber o tamanho de um *vetor*, eu posso usar apenas o
>   `nomedovetor.Length`, certo?

Depende, se for um *array* multidimensional o [`Array.GetLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) deve ser mais apropriado, ele recebe como argumento a dimensão da *array*, e retornará a quantidade de elementos de tal *array*, o [`Array.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) irá retornar todos os elementos de todas as *arrays*.

> Poderiam me explicar esse *0* e *1* entre parêntesis?

Esses valores indicam a dimensão da *array* que você quer obter o comprimento,
`Array.GetLength(0)` é o mesmo que [`Array.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), quando aplicado numa *array* de **uma** dimensão.

Veja um comparativo entre ambas:

```
string[,] matriz = new string[,]{
    {"1.1", "1.2", "1.3"},
    {"2.1", "2.2", "2.3"},
    {"3.1", "3.2", "3.3"}
};

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Length: {0}", matriz.Length));          // 9
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("GetLength: {0}", matriz.GetLength(0))); // 3
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/B7sFJw)